# front light blinking and beep sound

Tags: macbook-pro

Just two days back, I bought a MacBook Pro. I have just decreased the resolution of the display and started one game. Suddenly, my MacBook made an annoying beep sound and the front light was also blinking. After I restarted the system, everything seemed fine.

I just want to know what the problem was?

Edit: So the problem is reproducible. Whenever I start the game, the MacBook Pro starts flashing the front light and beeping.

Comment: If "Now everything is fine", what are you asking? Do you want to know why this happened? A way to fix this without restarting? Please edit you question to tell us what you want in the answers.

Comment: @Vivart As Slick mentioned in his answer, please add the blink pattern and the beep pattern, as well as what game you're playing and what MacBook Pro you have (13"/15"/17", processor speed, RAM amount, whether you've changed the RAM at all, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You need to let us know how many times the light blinks, because they are diagnostic indicators. If it's blinking 3 times then pause, then 3 times again then it's an indication of a bad RAM. If it beeps 3 times, it's also an indication of bad ram.
However, if it blinks 5 times and pauses, then the battery might need diagnostics or replacing. So check.

Comment: I agree. Slightly more information is needed.